# Hibernate 3.6 classMetaData exposes composite-id class?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Say, my hibernate-mapping has the below entry

```
<class name="foo.Person" table="person" lazy="false">  
    <composite-id name="personId" class="foo.PersonId">
        <key-property name="FIRST_NAME" type="string" column="FIRST_NAME"/>    
        <key-property name="LAST_NAME" type="string" column="FIRST_NAME"/>    
    </composite-id>
    <property name="AGE" type="int" node="AGE" column="AGE"/>
</class>
```

Is there any way I could use org.hibernate.metadata.ClassMetadata or its subclasses like AbstractEntityPersister SingleTableEntityPersister to find the composite-id class name "foo.PersonId"? I though it should be easy but I just cannot find it even by examining the ClassMetaData object in debug mode. I could use getIdentifierPropertyName and getPropertyColumnNames to find personId and FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME, but just cannot get the class name "foo.PersonId".

I notice org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration has getClassMappings and I could see the foo.PersonId is there, but I use Spring to initialize hibernate SessionFactory and I do not use cfg.xml, so I do not know how to get an instance of Configuration for my need.

Answer (score 0):

```
ClassMetaData c;
c.IdentifierType.ReturnedClass;
```

Comment: Thanks Firo, will take a look!  Sorry for the late feedback!